# how to store session when clicking LINK <a>

Tags: php, jquery, session

Is it possible to `store session` when clicking `<a>` in php??

If yes, how can I accomplished that? then that `SESSION variable` will be concatenate to JQUERY like this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   serviceName = '<?php $_SESSION['sessname'] . ".php";?>';

   if(serviceName!=""){
   $('.main_content').load(serviceName);
   }
</script>
```

is possible what I' trying to do?

Thank you in advance.!

Comment: No you cannot store in SESSION onclick of anchor tag that way, you need to use AJAX.

Comment: Ok sir. Can you provide some code snippet of how to use of `AJAX` sir? I'm not very familiar with AJAX.

Comment: **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23322211/2513523)** may help

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate your value properly:

```
serviceName = '<?php echo $_SESSION["sessname"]' . '.php ;?>';
```

Comment: Ok thanks about that. But how about storing `SESSION` when clicking `<a>`? Is it possible??

Comment: You need to call a script on the server, because that is where session data is stored; whether you call that script via AJAX in the background, or via a simple link does not really matter. (Although when you use a link, your browser will normally expect a new resource from the server to display afterwards.)